# Reason why a message was put to a DLQ in JBoss

Tags: jboss, jms, dead-letter

Assume I have a Queue with a DLQ, no redelivery. (Runtime) Exceptions during the processing of a message (in an MDB) cause the message to be sent to the DLQ, so I can decide how to deal with it. So far so good.

But I think in many situations it would be nice to know WHY the message was not processed properly, in other words what was the exception in the MDB?

I think from the technical point of view it should be fairly easy to attach the exception (or at least its stack trace as a string) to the message sent to the DLQ e.g. in a JMS property.

So far I was not able to find out if/how it is possible in JBoss (any version), or in any other JMS implementations/app servers.

Anyone knowing if this, or something similar is possible? Or why it is not possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?